# Accuracy of liquid level measurement using sonar sensor

Tags: home-automation

Is it a good way to measure liquid level in a water tank using a general purpose sonar sensor? How can echoes from the tank walls affect measurement accuracy?

I have a cylinder shaped **horizontal** 700L water tank, used for emergency water supply. I need to measure the water level with approx. 5% accuracy and display it in my kitchen.

[image: sonar sensor]

**UPDATE! Today I found this helpful page: [Home Heating Hacking Part 1 or How to Measure an Oil Tank](http://alaskanshade.blogspot.ch/2013/12/home-heating-hacking-part-1-or-how-to.html).
I had no time to realize my idea, but it's exactly what I wanted to do. So take a look.**

Comment: How is this cylinder placed? Horizontal, or standing upright.

Comment: Water tank is placed horizontally.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project - you might just have to try it!

Comment: Since you seem to have everything... Just test it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've implemented this on my 2 x 23,000 litre water tanks using 2x hc-sr04 sensors mounted on the tank lids and a nano in the pump house. Yes water is a good hard reflective surface to bounce the ultrasonic sound waves off. My tanks have an overflow outlet but not sure how well the eletronic will last? However they are cheap to replace. It is only early days but the overall the results are looking good.
Couple of points:

1.polling occurs hourly.

2.I only power the ultrasonic sensor just before taking a reading.

3.Has a sound detection sensor to alert on water pump overrun, ie a leak.

good luck

Comment: So it works.

I wonder maybe it's possible to increase the accuracy of the measurement  by putting two ~15cm PVC pipes on transducers. It could avoid receiving echo signals. What do you think?

Comment: Maybe the pipes would help? Basically you want good echos off the waters surface so mount the sensor firmly as square on to the surface as possible. I would be more inclined to buy a more accurate Ultrasonic sensor. The HC-SR04 have a resolution of 1 cm but others like the US-100 are down to the 1mm and have built-in temperature adjusted readings.